# Why does Google hangouts support sharing desktop without Chrome Extension in latest Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, frontend

As far as I know, in browser, such as Chrome, sharing desktop or application needs a Chrome Extension to work, eg:

```
chrome.permissions.request({
    permissions: ['desktopCapture'],
}
```

But why does Google Hangouts do not need any extension to capture desktop?

Is there any API of JavaScript for this?

Comment: Google whitelists API access for its own stuff. It's convenient to be a browser developer.

Comment: webRTC stuff in latest versions of chrome is avoid a install extension for screensharing too, but earlier it was nessusary. Hangouts are use webRTC. May be it related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of now, Google Hangouts *does* use an extension, it's just integrated into Chrome to the point of not being visible.

Source: [Chromium issue to remove this special treatment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=850536)

You can test that it is (stealthily) installed by manually opening

```
chrome-extension://nkeimhogjdpnpccoofpliimaahmaaome/background.html
```

At the same time, [work is ongoing](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6744724455030784) to support WebRTC spec for screen sharing (`getDisplayMedia`) in Chrome. It's not yet enabled by default in released Chrome versions, but will be very soon (code is already in the codebase).

Implementation tracking: [Chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=326740)

Comment: `getDisplayMedia` is under flag in Chrome 70  https://addpipe.com/blog/screen-capture-in-chrome-70-with-getdisplaymedia/